# Getting MYSQL DB info via bash

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I'm using some bash code which I got off another post on here

```
#!/bin/sh

users=$(mysql --user=user --password=password --database=$db -h _IP ADDRESS) -s --       execute="select$ users from db limit 1;"|cut -f1)

echo "$users"
```

The database is DB and the table is users basically I want to be able to get a user count from the table but when I run the script I get

```
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'execute=select users from db limit 1;'
```

any idea what i'm doing wrong or a better way of doing it? if I do

```
select * form users;
```

on the mysql server itself it returns 12 rows in set (0.00 sec) 12 being the number of users, so I just want my script to query the user table on database DB and return the number of rows ie 12.

Answer (score 1):

```
users_count=$(
    mysql --user user_name --password=password  -h x.x.x.x <<EOF | tail -n 1
    select count(1) from mysql.user;
EOF
)
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the order of your params is wrong...

MYSQL is telling you that 'execute=select users from db limit 1;' is in the position of the database parameter.

Try something like this:

```
mysql --user user_name --password=password -e 'select users from db_schema.table limit 1;'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this:

```
mysql -u username --password=password -h hostname database_name -e 'select count(1) from table limit 1;'
```